# Laplace transform of a PDE

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I am learning how to use Laplace transforms to solve PDEs. In case of an expression like

\begin{equation}
\int_{r}^{\infty} f(x,t) g(x) dx
\end{equation}

the resulting Laplace transform (*with respect to t*) is relatively simple if the expression is first differentiated by $r$:

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial}{\partial r} \int_{r}^{\infty} f(x,t) g(x) dx = -f(r, t) g(r)
\end{equation}

and

\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L} ( -f(r, t) g(r) ) = -g(r) F(r,s)
\end{equation}

Now I have been working with a similar expression:

\begin{equation}
\int_{r}^{\infty} f(x,t) g(x-r) dx
\end{equation}

However, in this case, the derivative with respect to $r$ does not simplify the expression:

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial}{\partial r} \int_{r}^{\infty} f(x,t) g(x-r) dx = -f(r, t) g(0) - \int_{r}^{\infty} f(x,t) g'(x-r) dx 
\end{equation}

and I could not obtain a simplified expression with the Laplace transform. Is there another way to simplify the expression above?

---

EDIT:

It occurred to me that the term above is a convolution of $f$ and $g$:

\begin{equation}
(f \ast g)(r) = \int_{r}^{\infty} f(x,t) g(x-r) dx
\end{equation}

In this case, is it valid to say that the Laplace transform (this time with respect to $r$) can be defined as:

\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L} \left( \int_{r}^{\infty} f(x,t) g(x-r) dx \right) = F(s,t)G(s) ?
\end{equation}

Comment: $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ should be changed to $\frac{\partial}{\partial r}$

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, I corrected it in the question.

Comment: What is the PDE?

Comment: @ShuhaoCao the whole PDE: 
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial f(r,t)}{\partial t} = -2 f(r, t) \left( \int_{0}^{r} g(x) (r -x +1) d x \right) + 4 \int_{r}^{\infty} f(x,t) \left( \int_{0}^{x-r} g(w) d w \right) d x 
\end{equation}